# TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Я пытаюсь загрузить, а затем открыть файл excel (отчет), созданный marketplace с помощью openpyxl.

```
import requests
import config
import openpyxl

link = 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot' + config.TOKEN + '/documents/file_66.xlsx'

def save_open(link):
    
    filename = link.split('/')[-1]
    r = requests.get(link)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(r.content)

    wb = openpyxl.open ('file_66.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active

    cell = ws['B2'].value
    print (cell)

save_open(link)
```

После запуска этого кода я получил следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\Documents\myPython\bot_WB\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    save_open(link)
  File "C:\Users\Home\Documents\myPython\bot_WB\main.py", line 14, in save_open
    wb = openpyxl.open ('file_66.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.fills = fills
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Python 3.9\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
[Finished in 1.6s]
```

Если открыть Свойства/Подробно, то там будет указано, что этот файл был создан "Go Exelize" (автор: xuri). Чтобы открыть этот файл через Python, нужно разделить код на две части. Во-первых: загрузить файл. Затем нужно вручную открыть его с помощью MS Excel, сохранить файл и закрыть его (после этого "Go Excelize" переключится на "Microsoft Excel"). И только после этого можно правильно запустить вторую часть кода без ошибок. Кто-нибудь может помочь мне справиться с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой. При открытии файла библиотека **openpyxl** порождала ошибку "**TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments**":

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Mamontov.virtualenvs\flask-J0o7RS21\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
> value = expected_type(value)
> TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

Причём проблема возникала только на автоматически сгенерированных xlsx-файлах (выгрузки, отчёты, регистры из различных систем). 
И если открыть **такой** файл и пересохранить его вручную, то потом библиотека **openpyxl** обрабатывает пересохранённый файл без ошибок. Очевидно при пересохранении меняется внутренняя структура файла. Кроме того размер нового файла значительно больше.

Чтобы избежать ручного пересохранения установил **pandas** и **xlrd**:

1. В терминале:

```
pip install pandas==1.1.5
pip install xldr==1.2.0
```

**ВАЖНО:** библиотеки нужно ставить именно указанных версий (**pandas==1.1.5** и **xldr==1.2.0**). Свежий pandas поддерживает только последние версии xlrd, которые в свою очередь вызывают ошибку при открытии xlsx-файлов. Замкнутый круг.
2. В консоле:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'd:\\flask_project\\files\\123.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(url, engine='xlrd', header=0, skiprows=1)
data.head()
```

==========================================
**UPD:**
Немного помучившись с подбором библиотек, написал скрипт для обработки экселевского файла через библиотеку xlrd. Все строки пишутся в словарь, где:
ключи словаря - названия колонок
значения словаря - данные из столбцов (в виде списков)
На основе словаря создаётся DataFrame. Теперь с данными работать намного удобнее.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook(url)
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

xlsx_dict = {sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=i): []
             for i in range(sh.ncols)}

for i in range(1, sh.nrows):
    for n, (k, v) in enumerate(xlsx_dict.items()):
        v.append(sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=n))

data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(xlsx_dict)
print(data.columns)
print(data.head())
```